# How to distinct on second column from the same table?

Tags: sql

I have a problem, where first field in `unique/distinct` and the second field is like concatenated string. i am looking for the distinct rows to be displayed in the second concatenated column not on the first column and i need in the same seq of columns, for ex:

```
1stcolumn 2ndcolumn(concatenated)
100       ABC-123-PQR
101       ABC-123-PQR
102       ABC-123-PQR
104       ABC-123-STU
```

in the above example i need to select only `ABC-123-PQR` AND `ABC-123-STU`, i don't care on the first column values.

Comment: Why not a simple `GROUP BY`? `SELECT secondcolumn
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY secondcolumn`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `DISTINCT` keyword?

```
SELECT DISTINCT col2 FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(col1), col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col2
```